# Trying to add the first & last integer of a list in python

Tags: python

Hi I have just started an online course for python, just for me, and one of the exercises is asking me to add the first and list integer from a list you input, I think I have it, but not too sure as it keeps giving me an error,

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

my code is

```
userList = list(map(int, input().split(',')))
intTotal = userList[1] + userList[len userList]
print (intTotal)
```

now, how I understand it the, **[1]** would be the first userList value, as it is the first position in the list, and the **[len userList]** should give me last position as it is giving the length of list as position number.

then it should print the variable intTotal

If you could show me where i am going wrong if it all that would be ace!

Comment: use `userList[-1]` to get the last element. `userList[len(userList)]` will give an out of range error because lists are zero indexed.

Comment: This code won't run.

Comment: You're error is generated by the first line that means splitted input is contain invalid literals for converting to integer like a punctuation or just a whitespace.

Comment: What's the input you're giving the script? Are there any non-numbers in it? We need a [mcve] to debug your code.

Comment: You are making us guess about a lot of things. You don't show the input, your code doesn't run and you don't show us the stack trace that would tell us which line has the problem. How about a new example that works and uses a canned string instead of user input so we can see what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is most likely that your input is something like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5,`

When you use `split(',')` on this, you will have an extra empty entry at the end of your list that you must account for.  You can check for this in a list comprehension.

To access the last element of the list, you may use `arr[len(arr)-1]`, or in Python which supports negative indexing, `arr[-1]`.

Here is a working version of your code with the above changes made:

```
userList = [int(x.strip()) for x in input().split(',') if x]
intTotal = userList[0] + userList[-1]
print (intTotal)
```

Sample run:

```
>>>1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
6
```

You could make this even more robust to filter out bad input by using `isdigit()`, which would allow for the user to enter letters, but it would only add the first and last numbers entered:

```
userList = [int(x) for x in input().split(',') if x.isdigit()]
```

Sample run:

```
>>> 1,2,a,3,4,6,b,4
5
```